# Is there a switch to ignore undefined namespace prefixes in LXML?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm parsing a non-compliant XML file ([Sphinx's](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) xmlpipe2 format) and would like LXML parser to ignore the fact that there are unresolved namespace prefixes.

An example of the Sphinx XML:

```
<sphinx:schema>
    <sphinx:field name="subject"/>
    <sphinx:field name="content"/>
    <sphinx:attr name="published" type="timestamp"/>
    <sphinx:attr name="author_id" type="int" bits="16" default="1"/>
</sphinx:schema>
```

I'm aware of passing a parser keyword option to try and recover broken XML, e.g.

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.parse('sphinxTest.xml', parser)
```

but the above does not ignore the prefix, it removes it.

I could create a target which adds in the removed prefix e.g.

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(target = AddPrefix())
```

where `AddPrefix()` is a class which adds in the prefix to every attribute tag.
Is there a simpler way to do this? 
Eventually i want to programmatically write Sphinx's xmlpipe2 format cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

Add `xmlns:sphinx="bogus"` to the root element.